# rViz does not reflect my initial pose

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a blank map and setting the initialpose by publishing to the initialpose topic.  I expected that rViz would subscribe to this and that the initial pose in rViz would reflect it.  But publishing different initial pose's does not change the initial location of my robot in rViz.  Why is that?

I guess I don't understand how rViz should respond to initialpose messages.  I run the rbx1 fake_nav_test and either manually in rViz or use rqt_publisher to send an initialpose message.  I expect the robot to jump to the initial pose on the rViz screen, but nothing happens.  This is all in the map reference frame.

I am using an example from ROS By Example Volume 1. The files are here: https://github.com/pirobot/rbx1 and I am using rbx1/rbx1_nav/launch/fake_nav_test.launch. I run roslaunch rbx1_nav fake_nav_test.launch.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234098/rviz-does-not-reflect-my-initial-pose/) by [mitch](https://answers.ros.org/users/22960/mitch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-05-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-05-11**:
This could be due to various reasons:

1. `rviz` does never subscribe to initialpose. You can add a Pose Display to doso
2. do you have a localization running? If not, the topic goes nowhere.
3. what is the `fixed_frame` in `rviz`? If it is not`map`, the transform could look unchanged on a blank map

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-05-11**:
can you please provide a minimal example of the files that you actually start? best put it on github and link above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is resolved.  It was a bug in the indigo branch of the fake_localization node of the example I was trying.  Now it works as I expected it should.

---

Originally posted by [mitch](https://answers.ros.org/users/22960/mitch/) with karma: 23 on 2016-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-05-12**:
great, glad you found it...